# How to save/export a Spark ML Lib model to PMML?

Tags: hadoop, deployment, machine-learning, apache-spark, modeling

I'd like to train a model using Spark ML Lib but then be able to export the model in a platform-agnostic format. Essentially I want to decouple how models are created and consumed.

My reason for wanting this decoupling is so that I can deploy a model in other projects. E.g.:

- Use the model to perform predictions in a separate standalone program which doesn't depend on Spark for the evaluation.
- Use the model with existing projects such as OpenScoring and provide APIs which can make use of the model.
- Load an existing model back into Spark for high throughput prediction.

Has anyone done something like this with Spark ML Lib?

Comment: You can try [jpmml](https://github.com/jpmml). I have no practical knowledge using jpmml but I think that is what you need weither you are using Java or Scala.

Comment: I was looking into JPMML but I was not seeing any clear approaches on converting the ML Lib models to JPMML out of the box

Comment: you have to read the documentation...

Comment: Have you seen the following Github issue: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3062#discussion_r19769621

Comment: @eliasah what documentation exactly are you referring to? user1808924 I have not seen that issue. That PR appears to tackle the serialization of learners but not of transformers, so it looks like I would need to fork spark and develop PMML serialization logic for each additional feature transformer (scaling, feature extraction, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Version of Spark 1.4 now has support for this. See [latest documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html). Not all models are available (see to be supported (see [the JIRA issue SPARK-4587](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4587)).

HTHs